# Hypothesis testing: Significant difference between multiple iid samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, population

I have four samples

```
x1 = [1,1,2,5]
x2 = [1,1,1,2]
x3 = [1,5,5,5]
x4 = [1,1,2,2]
```

I am looking for a way to test whether the four populations are siginificantly different from each other. The only possible symbols the sample are 1, 2, 5. The symbols are ordinal.

Is there a hypothesis test that does this? I was thinking of pair-wise application of students t-test, but i cannot make any normality assumptions. Ideally, I am looking for an implementation in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test you are looking for is the Kruskal-Wallis H Test. It is the non-parametric equivalent of a one-way ANOVA.

The assumptions are:

1. The dependent variable is at least ordinal
2. The independent variable consists of min 2 independent groups
3. The observations are independent. That is, there cannot be multiple measurements originating from the same entity (e.g. a person cannot be part of population x1 and population x2)
4. The distributions of the populations have to be identically except for their scale parameter (the histograms should have the same shape in each group, however they are allowed to be at different x values)

Using Python 3.8.5 and Scipy 1.5.1 you can do the test as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kruskal

x1 = [1,1,2,5]
x2 = [1,1,1,2]
x3 = [1,5,5,5]
x4 = [1,1,2,2]

kruksal_test = kruskal(x1, x2, x3, x4)
print("Test statistic: Chi^2 = ", kruksal_test.statistic, ", p =", kruksal_test.pvalue)
```

```
Test statistic: Chi^2 =  4.062500000000004 , p = 0.2547938670602861
```

Comment: Is this the usual Kruskal-Wallis test?

Comment: @Dave yes, that is correct!

Comment: @bk_  that shouldn’t be an issue usually. The test only considers the **order** of the values, not the values itself. So the results for values 2 and 3 should be the same as 2E-50 and 5 E-50.

Comment: @bk_  you can try remapping the values. But I would be surprised if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, 2 and 5 are the only values that the random variable can take, it might not make sense to treat it as continuous or  metric variable at all. Do the outcomes carry cardinal or ordinal meaning?

If not, or when making this assumption, you can use a 3 x 4 contingency table with 3 discrete categories ("1", "2" and "5") and 4 populations, with respective counts in each cell, and get an overall p-value based on a $\chi^2$ test. In R (sorry, no python here), this would be:

```
#define dataframe
df <- data.frame(
population = c(rep("x1",4), rep("x2",4), rep("x3",4), rep("x4",4)),
outcome    = c(1,1,2,5, 1,1,1,2, 1,5,5,5, 1,1,2,2))

#chisq test
chisq.test(table(df$population,df$outcome))

X-squared = 9, df = 6, p-value = 0.1736
```

If they do, you can run a Kruskal-Wallis test, which is rank-based, without making distributional assumptions:

```
kruskal.test(outcome ~ population, data = df)

Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 4.0625, df = 3, p-value = 0.2548
```

In any case, the samples are very small to draw meaningful conclusions and you are very likely to make Type II errors when using null hypothesis testing with usual significance thresholds.

Comment: For such a small sample size, Fisher's exact test is both feasible and preferable. For small sample sizes, the chi-squared test will be overconfident, since the approximation assumptions are not met. The Fisher method is more computationally expensive, so its use is limited to small sample sizes, but that's exactly where the chisq test fails. Basically, any time you have the ability to run the Fisher test instead of chisq, you should. With this data, the Fisher p-value is almost twice as high at 0.3.